# Regex for for Phone Numbers allowing for only 6 to 20 characters

Tags: regex

Regex beginner here. I've been trying to tackle this rule for phone numbers to no avail and would appreciate some advice:

1. Minimum 6 characters
2. Maximum 20 characters
3. Must contain numbers
4. Can contain these symbols `()+-`.
5. Do not match if all the numbers included are the same (ie. `111111`)

I managed to build two of the following pieces but I'm unable to put them together.

Here's what I've got:

```
(^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d)
([0-9()-+.,]{6,20})
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what flavor or regex?

Comment: May it _additionally_ contain the symbols or could the "phone number" consist of only symbols?

Comment: What's with rule 5? There are valid phone numbers that consist entirely of the same number.

Comment: "what flavor or regex?"
- JS

"May it additionally contain the symbols or could the "phone number" consist of only symbols?"
- The former

"What's with rule 5? There are valid phone numbers that consist entirely of the same number. "
- Good point, but that was the decision to rule out spam / fake entries

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it by first getting a list of all possible phone numbers (thanks @CAustin for the suggested improvements):

```
lst_phone_numbers = re.findall('[0-9+()-]{6,20}',your_text)
```

And then filtering out the ones that do not comply with statement 5 using whatever programming language you're most comfortable.

Comment: You don't need to escape any of the characters that you escaped in that pattern, nor do you need to surround the entire thing in a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx:

```
(?:([\d()+-])(?!\1+$)){6,20}
```

Explained:

1. `(?:` creates a non-capturing group
2. `(\d|[()+-])` creates a group to match a digit, parenthesis, +, or -
3. `(?!\1+$)` this will not return a match if it matches the value found from #2 one or more times until the end of the string
4. `{6,20}` requires 6-20 matches from the non-capturing group in #1

Comment: Why `(\d|[()+-])` instead of just `([\d()+-])`?

Comment: Thanks, however the Regex is excluding matches if the number is repeated only once (eg. 112233 should be matching).

Only cases where there are no variations (ie. 1111111 or 222222) should not match.

Comment: @lwngy - I just tested it and it only returns false if the last two digits repeat. If you have `112234` then it returns true. To be honest, I'm not sure if you can do this strictly through RegEx. It sounds like a parser would be needed or something to dynamically change the plus sign in `\1+$` to the length of the String.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
((?:([0-9()+\-])(?!\2{5})){6,20})
```

So , this part `?!\2{5}` means how many times is allowed for each one from the pattern to be repeated like this `22222`  and i put `5` as example and you could change it as you want .